# Image overlap issue over Frame in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build following layout in XAML for Xamarin forms app.
[image]

Here is my code

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HeightRequest="350">
    <Frame
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        HasShadow="true"
        CornerRadius="10"
        Margin="20,25,20,25">
        <StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
    <Image
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,50,50"
        Source=“icon.png”/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

It works good on IOS but icon image is not shown correctly in android.
Please look at following screenshot.

[image]

Please help me to fix!

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms `2.5.0.121934` ?

Comment: sure, I am using latest version.

Comment: That is a bug in 2.5, there are a few other z-order issues also and due to the way the renderer works you can not use `RaiseChild` on the view in the page .actor either

Comment: Did you try to play with IsClippedToBounds property? See this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58048

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem overlaying the circle image over the frame in Android.

**Fix:** Please set Frame HasShadow property to "false" and that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="350">
            <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1" 
                   BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="true"
                   CornerRadius="10"
                   Margin="20,25,20,25">
                <StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" Padding="0,0,0,0"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,50,50" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                <Image Margin="0,0,0,0"  Aspect="AspectFill" Source="icon.png"/>
            </Frame>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: did you really try my code because it is work fine for me. Please Check above screenshot.

Comment: When you add HasShadow="false" to frame of image, it doesn't work

Comment: @Passionate.C, it works fine on my side when I set `HasShadow="false"`.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT When I set HasShadow="false" to frame of image, it doesn't work in android

Comment: @Passionate.C, that' weird, it works fine on my side. Would you mind sharing a basic demo to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Did you try to add HasShadow="false" to frame that icon is placed and test in android? what is your xamarin forms version and visual studio?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT You can use circle icon to confirm that it works correctly in android?

Answer (score 0):

@nitish-gawde's answer didn't work for me with image's frame HasShadow set as false.
However the workaround that worked for me was to put the first frame inside another layout (say StackLayout):

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="350">
    <StackLayout
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" 
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1">

        <Frame
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="true"
               CornerRadius="10"
               Margin="20,25,20,25">
                <StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
</StackLayout

     <Frame HasShadow = "False"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" Padding="0,0,0,0"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,50,50" 
         VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <Image Margin="0,0,0,0"  Aspect="AspectFill" Source="icon.png"/>
      </Frame>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Screenshot:
[image]